# best practices: using directive prototypal scope inheritance versus scope isolate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/lesouthern/rLb2pL5a/3/

Such a directive can be written with either scope inheritance, or isolate.

```
.directive('myDirective1',function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            myDirective1Attribute1 : '=',
            myDirective1Attribute2 : '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $compile($element.contents());
        }
    }
})
.directive('myDirective2',function() {
    return {
        scope : true,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var _attrs = $scope.$eval($attrs.myDirective2);
            $scope.myDirective2Attribute1 = $scope.$eval(_attrs.myDirective2attribute1);
            $scope.myDirective2Attribute2 = $scope.$eval(_attrs.myDirective2attribute2);
        }
    }
})
```

Under what circumstances is it better to use scope inheritance? When is it better to isolate scope?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use isolated scope in your directives as much as possible. 
There are 2 reasons.

1. **Simplifies component structure.**

   - Directive in Angular can be considered as a custom component and for the component you should declare it's dependencies. In case of scope inheritance these dependencies are implicit that makes them hard to track. With declared dependencies in isolated scope you will always have explicit outlook of things (in scope) needed to make your component working.
2. **Ability to reuse components across apps**
   If your component will be well designed and well implemented you won't need to have some particular vars in scope, you will need to specify dependencies aka public interface and it's done - you can build reusable components following this approach.
3. **Much easier to write tests for simple components instead of monster controlers**

Answer (score 0):

Almost always is better to use isolated scope because it makes your directives more reusable. The directive does not need to know anything about the parent scope structure.

On the other hand there are some valid case when you don't need isolated scope for example if you write a directive for some jquery plugin which does not modify the scope. Also keep in mind that you can have only one directive with isolated scope per element.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought my alternative may help other users facing your issue.

Instead of using `scope` directly, I suggest to use the alias syntax on your controller in your `html`.

This [less traditional syntax](http://www.johnpapa.net/do-you-like-your-angular-controllers-with-or-without-sugar/) simplifies your code and probably makes clearer what you're trying to do to somebody reading your code.

From [ng-controller spec](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController):

> Using `controller as`
>
> - makes it obvious which controller you are accessing in the template when multiple controllers apply to an element.
> - If you are writing your controllers as classes you have easier access to the properties and methods, which will appear on the scope,
>     from inside the controller code.
> - Since there is always a . in the bindings, you don't have to worry about prototypal inheritance masking primitives.

[Check out also this awesome explanation of the advantages of alias syntax](http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ursus- while I appreciate your response, the topic is when to close scope on directives, and when to keep it open. Nathan LeClaire summarizes my concerns in item 4 here: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/